Calling SOAP Web Services using APEX_WEB_SERVICE
I am having issues trying to consume a SOAP web service. I getting Error: ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed as a response. Bellow is the piece of code I am using.
PLease advice
declare
    l_token                VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_envelope             CLOB;
    l_xml                  XMLTYPE;
    l_result               VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

 l_envelope := q'!<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>!';
   l_envelope := l_envelope || '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://ws.mcel.co.mz/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ws:getMsisdnAndAvailabilityFromSerial>
         <simCardSerial>8925801191077167862</simCardSerial>
         <loginInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nomeAplicacao>***</nomeAplicacao>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <usuario>***</usuario>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <password>***</password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <token>***</token>
         </loginInfo>
      </ws:getMsisdnAndAvailabilityFromSerial>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

    -- Aqui, certifique-se de que todas as instâncias de objetos não são nulas
    IF l_envelope IS NOT NULL THEN
        l_xml := XMLTYPE.createXML(l_envelope);
    ELSE
        -- Lidar com o caso onde l_envelope é NULL
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Envelope é NULL');
    END IF;
--
    --   l_xml := xmltype(l_envelope);
        dbms_output.put_line('Envelope SOAP: ' || l_envelope);
        l_xml := apex_web_service.make_request(p_url => 'http://ServerIP/SimRegWebService', p_action => 'http://ServerIP/SimRegWebService/getMsisdnAndAvailabilityFromSerial'
        , p_envelope => l_envelope);

        dbms_output.put_line('Resposta SOAP: ' || l_xml.getclobval());
        l_result := apex_web_service.parse_xml(p_xml => l_xml, p_xpath => '', 
        p_ns => 'xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://ws.mcel.co.mz/"');

        dbms_output.put_line('Resultado: ' || l_result);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Erro: ' || SQLERRM);

    END;

I cant figure it out what is wrong because it is running fine on SOAP-UI
